# Android - shadow on text?

Tags: android

I am wondering how to add shadow on text in android?

I have the following code which is applied on a bitmap and I wanted to be shadowed...

```
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(55);
paint.setFakeBoldText(false);
paint.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK); //This only shadows my whole view...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you must have a ShadowRadius.

Comment: You should mark the answer @fhucho left as the correct answer; I was trying to do the same thing and missed it the first time I saw this post, as no answer was marked as correct.  The answer upvoted many times is misleading, as it doesn't relate to adding the shadow programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add opaque "shadow" (outline) to Android TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106454/add-opaque-shadow-outline-to-android-textview)

Answer (score 398, accepted):

You should be able to add the style, like this (taken from source code for Ringdroid):

```
  <style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
  </style>
```

And in your layout, use the style like this:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText"
       android:gravity="center" />
```

Edit: the source code can be viewed here: https://github.com/google/ringdroid

Edit2:
To set this style programmatically, you'd do something like this (modified from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime/4632208#4632208) to match ringdroid's resources from above)

```
TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
infoTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),  
       R.style.AudioFileInfoOverlayText);
```

The signature for `setTextAppearance` is

> public void setTextAppearance (Context context, int resid)
>
> Since: API Level 1
>   Sets the text color, size, style, hint color, and
>   highlight color from the specified TextAppearance resource.

Comment: But the OP is asking for custom widgets!

Comment: That may be, but there's nothing to suggest that he couldn't use this method on an ImageView.  I assumed he was painting directly because he couldn't figure it out otherwise.

Comment: awesome... adds much needed depth to the standard font and makes it look 10X better on a solid background.

Comment: @Farhan see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime/4632208#4632208

Comment: I would like to mention that style (the .xml file) should be defined in /res/values directory and has the <resources> tag as the root one, otherwise it won't work. Good luck!

Comment: is there reference for it...i can't find it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It's the documentation for [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: i meant where is shadow in it

Comment: I don't follow. When you go to the documentation for TextView linked in my last comment, you don't see `android:shadow*` styles? I do.

Comment: Really helped, thumbs up bro

Comment: perfect answer :)

Answer (score 77):

You can do both in code and XML. Only 4 basic things to be set.

1. shadow color
2. Shadow Dx - it specifies the X-axis offset of shadow. You can give -/+ values, where -Dx draws a shadow on the left of text and +Dx on the right
3. shadow Dy - it specifies the Y-axis offset of shadow. -Dy specifies a shadow above the text and +Dy specifies below the text.
4. shadow radius - specifies how much the shadow should be blurred at the edges. Provide a small value if shadow needs to be prominent. Else otherwise.

e.g.

```
    android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow_color"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="0.01"
```

This draws a prominent shadow on left-lower side of text.
In code, you can add something like this;

```
    TextView item = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    item.setText(R.string.text);
    item.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.general_text_color));
    item.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -2, 2,   getResources().getColor(R.color.text_shadow_color));
```

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:padding="20dp" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textview"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>         android:shadowColor="#000"
>         android:shadowDx="0"
>         android:shadowDy="0"
>         android:shadowRadius="50"
>         android:text="Text Shadow Example1"
>         android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
>         android:textSize="28dp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textview2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>         android:text="Text Shadow Example2"
>         android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
>         android:textSize="28dp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

In the above XML layout code, the textview1 is given with Shadow effect in the layout. below are the configuration items are

**android:shadowDx** – specifies the X-axis offset of shadow. You can give -/+ values, where -Dx draws a shadow on the left of text and +Dx on the right

**android:shadowDy** – it specifies the Y-axis offset of shadow. -Dy specifies a shadow above the text and +Dy specifies below the text.

**android:shadowRadius** – specifies how much the shadow should be blurred at the edges. Provide a small value if shadow needs to be prominent.
android:shadowColor – specifies the shadow color

---

**Shadow Effect on Android TextView pragmatically**

Use below code snippet to get the shadow effect on the second TextView pragmatically.

> ```
> TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
> textv.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.RED);
> ```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you brother, first text view helped me what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <style name="WhiteTextWithShadow" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

then use as

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:text="Today, May 21"
            style="@style/WhiteTextWithShadow"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve a shadow like the one that Android does in the Launcher, we're managing these values. They're useful if you want to create TextViews that will appear as a Widget, without a background.

```
android:shadowColor="#94000000"
android:shadowDy="2"
android:shadowRadius="4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Draw 2 texts: one gray (it will be the shadow) and on top of it draw the second text (y coordinate 1px more then shadow text).

Comment: Thanks guys for your posts.
I did solve it by using two paint objects and using the setShadaowLayer on one of the paint-object.

Comment: This might look ok if you use alpha, but won't look like the nice, soft, declaratively-set shadow.