# Shadow Effect for a Text in Android?

Tags: android, textview, shadow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - shadow on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text)

How can i make shadow effect text in a `TextView`.

Any Idea?

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Perhaps you'd consider using [android:shadowColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:shadowColor), `android:shadowDx`, `android:shadowDy`, `android:shadowRadius`; alternatively [setShadowLayer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29) ?

Comment: This does not make any changes. I think it works. But the values that i set is a problem. can you post the sample value for `shadowdx` , `shadowdy` and `shadowradious`?

Comment: You should post your code. Meanwhile, check the markup in examples like http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/ (scroll down to Text Shadow section).

Comment: what are the units for the shadowdx,shadowdy and shadowradius

Comment: @androiddeveloper Pixels.

Comment: @skywall Why are they in pixels, while everything is dp ? it doesn't make sense .. :(

Comment: @androiddeveloper "If it's not specified then the unit is always in px. – Romain Guy" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854935/textviewshadowdx-dy-radius-in-dip

Comment: @skywall But for XML layouts, it's always DP that's encouraged to be used.

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 478):

put these in values/colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="light_font">#FBFBFB</color>
    <color name="grey_font">#ff9e9e9e</color>
    <color name="text_shadow">#7F000000</color>
    <color name="text_shadow_white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your layout xml here are some example TextView's

**Example of Floating text on Light with Dark shadow**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_example1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textSize="14sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="@color/light_font"
                  android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                  android:shadowDx="1"
                  android:shadowDy="1"
                  android:shadowRadius="2" />
```

[image]

**Example of Etched text on Light with Dark shadow**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_example2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/light_font"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                android:shadowDx="-1"
                android:shadowDy="-1"
                android:shadowRadius="1" />
```

[image]

**Example of Crisp text on Light with Dark shadow**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_example3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_font"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow_white"
                android:shadowDx="-2"
                android:shadowDy="-2"
                android:shadowRadius="1" />
```

[image]

Notice the positive and negative values... I suggest to play around with the colors/values yourself but ultimately you can adjust these settings to get the effect your looking for.

Comment: In my case it was not visible in android editor preview but it works on real device as charm!!!

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 68):

```
TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textv.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Seems to ignore the color and use whatever the text is using

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 2):

**Complete answer**

**Add these 2 line to the parent view otherwise Text Shadow will be clipped when view bound are smaller than shadow offset**

> android:clipChildren="false"
>
> android:clipToPadding="false"

EXAMPLE:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
           ... >

        <TextView
         style="@style/TextShadowStyle"
          ....
            />
```

Text Shadow Style:

```
 <style name="TextShadowStyle">
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">10</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">10</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    </style>
```