# TextView:shadowDx/Dy/Radius in dip?

Tags: android

How can we specify a TextView's shadowDx/Dy/Radius values in dip? Right now I have:

```
<style name="foo">
  <item name="android:shadowDx">-1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

I can't seem to specify "1dip" in these places. Is there a way to do it other than setting them in code and doing the device density multiplication ourselves?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the only way, sorry :(

Comment: what are the units of the shadow parameters? is it px , pt , dp , sp ... ?

Comment: Is this going to be changed? Kind of annoying! also, why does a radius of 0.1 get converted to 0 and therefore not show any shadow?

Comment: Bug raised here, for those who would like to change this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180432&can=5&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:shadowDx) is really lacking here. The unit of measurement is not specified!

Answer (score 25):

I made an overridden TextView with custom xml attributes to handle this in a convenient way.

Which is also available as a library: https://github.com/rongi/text-view-shadow-dips

```
public class TextViewShadowDips extends TextView {

public TextViewShadowDips(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    final TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewShadowDips);
    // App can crash on some devices if shadow radius is more than 25 pixels
    // On Samsung Galaxy S6 this crash happens when you copy a text from an input field
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866928/ranges-for-radius-in-shadowradius-and-visiblity-in-textview?lq=1
    final float shadowRadius = Math.min(
        attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.TextViewShadowDips_shadowRadius, 0f),
        25f
    );
    final float shadowDx = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.TextViewShadowDips_shadowDx, 0f);
    final float shadowDy = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.TextViewShadowDips_shadowDy, 0f);
    final int shadowColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.TextViewShadowDips_shadowColor, 0);
    if (shadowColor != 0) {
        setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, shadowDx, shadowDy, shadowColor);
    } else {
        getPaint().clearShadowLayer();
    }
    attributes.recycle();
}
```

attrs.xml inside "values" resource folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TextViewShadowDips">
        <attr name="shadowRadius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="shadowDx" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="shadowDy" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="shadowColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <my.package.name.TextViewShadowDips 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:shadowColor="#000000"
        app:shadowRadius="2dp"
        app:shadowDx="2dp"
        app:shadowDy="2dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @boulder is it true that on some android versions the shadow feature won't work since it's not GPU supported, and needs to have something like :setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's not supported for drawing rects. Text drawing is ok on all android versions.

Comment: @boulder thank you. i was wondering why i couldn't achieve it for some views.

Comment: Thanks for this @nickes It's a shame we have to use this :( Feature request opened: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180432&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars Please star if you wish to see this feature

Comment: Please note that setting a shadowRadius > 25px will crash some devices. The shadow radius itself should NOT be specified in DP units but instead it should always be in PX units. This value specifies how blurry the shadow is, not how big the shadow is. The size of the shadow is determined by the size of the text.

Comment: @AndrewKelly thank you for report about the crash. About radius. Yes, the radius is a radius of blurriness of edges of the shadow. But why it should be in PX? It is still a radius and should be in DP.

Comment: A larger value for the radius just make things more blurry. It doesn't make sense to have this linked to DP. e.g. would you want things to be more blurry on xxhdpi devices compared to xhdpi devices? The blurriness should be the same on both.

Comment: Setting a shadowRadius of 8DP would give you 32PX on an xxhdpi device, so sticking with PX is best.

Answer (score 17):

As Romain says, you can't set dip values directly in XML. You can still do it in XML, though, without having to do messy scaling calculations in your code.

The trick is to have separate `values-hdpi`, `values-mdpi` and `values-ldpi` folders, in addition to your normal `values` folder. Inside each, create a separate `styles.xml` containing a style for your text with the shadow applied.

For example, you might have this in `values-mdpi/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="my_shadow">
  <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDy">-1.0</item>
  <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.0</item>
</style>
```

And in `values-hdpi/styles.xml`, you have the same style but with the values scaled for the higher density:

```
<style name="my_shadow">
  <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDy">-1.5</item>
  <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.5</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I strongly discourage this.  There is a fundamental assumption here that there is a fixed set of densities, which is not true.  For example, you haven't specified xhdpi or tvdpi (newer densities), so you won't get the correct value for those.

Comment: @hackbod But by that argument, one can never use density qualifiers, in any situation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using density buckets for his values.xml. This approach is fine.