# Ranges for radius in shadowRadius and visiblity in TextView

Tags: android, textview, transparency, opacity

I'd like to know what is the exact range of the radius in the `shadowRadius` property. In the documentation, they only say this value must be a float. That's fine but what is the range for the radius in Android? I mean, how do I set a 120º radius for instance?

Same problem for the visibility for `TextView`. In the documentation, they say I have to set a `#aarrggbb` hexadecimal color code. That's fine but again, what is the range for the visibility in Android? The value 100 (= 64 in hexadecimal) doesn't correspond at all to a maximum opacity. So what are the minimum / maximum opacities in Android?

Comment: You should accept answers by clicking on the tick by the answer that was most relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radius is a length not an angle and the range of opacity is 00 to FF using #aarrggbb.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My mathematical English is not so good so I mixed up the words "radius" and "angle" ;-) About the opacity I never used before this way of setting it up but now it's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3):

There is an undocumented range-limit on the `shadowRadius` property on some devices: 0-25.

If you exceed 25 on the Lenovo A3500 tablet for example, the following will show up in LogCat:

```
E/rsC++(14127): RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound
E/rsC++(14127): RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
E/rsC++(14127): RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
```

And your app will terminate **hard** without throwing an exception that you could react to.

Gotta love the way Android handles these things...

(Also see this question: [Android - Signal 11, RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048567/android-signal-11-rs-cpp-error-blur-radius-out-of-0-25-pixel-bound))

Comment: I've seen the same on a LG L90 phone. No exceptions, no visible errors, just the 3 lines in logcat. Since the range is undocumented and seemingly invisible to the JVM, it makes me think it's subject to change between devices (or between chipsets, for example). It's enough to make me shy away from using `shadowRadius` altogether. EDIT: It's an open issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73886