# Android - Signal 11, RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound

Tags: android

When upgrading my application to run on 4.4.2 devices I received the error

```
RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound
```

accompanied by a Signal 11 (native code) error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000028 (code=1)
```

The root of this issue took me a long time to locate with no results on Google or stack overflow and a search of my code for any use of 'blur' not revealing anything.

Comment: This really should not result in a native crash. So I reported it. Please feel free to star! https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73886

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Eventually I did manage to track the problem, which was in my styles.xml - in one place I used

```
<item name="android:shadowRadius">30</item>
```

on a style extending `android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView`. The fix for this issue was just to use a value within the range stated in the error, e.g.

```
<item name="android:shadowRadius">25</item>
```

I hope this helps somebody else with a similar problem from having to spend a long time locating their issue!

Comment: Helped. This is also valid when using TextView.setShadowLayer method.

Answer (score 9):

This also happens if you specify the shadowRadius in dp and the converted pixel radius is higher than 25.

So for example if you specify your radius to be 8dp and run the app on a xxxhdpi device (density multiplier 4), the effective radius in pixels is 32.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to go higher than a 25 pixel blur radius, then you can turn off hardware rendering.

```
android:layerType="software"
```

or

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

See the [Hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) documentation.

In my experience, turning off the "acceleration" didn't seem to negatively affect the performance for my particular app. However, there was a slightly noticeable difference in the quality of the blur.

With hardware rendering:

[image]

With software rendering:

[image]

*(The two images above were taken from a Xiaomi 2 phone running Android 5. Newer hardware and software might give different results.)*

This quality hit is undesirable but I found it to be acceptable for most cases. And there really wasn't another option since in addition to the above crash I was getting a lot of other very strange bugs when using hardware acceleration.