# Android text shadow units

Tags: android, text, shadow

Android text shadows have `shadowDx` and `shadowDy` to specify the shadow's offset. These are floats and are a factor rather than absolute units. The answer given here implies that there's no easy way of specifying the shadow's position in pixels or dips: [TextView:shadowDx/Dy/Radius in dip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854935/textviewshadowdx-dy-radius-in-dip)

So... what do the units mean? If I give a `shadowDx` of 1.5, that's 1.5 what? 1.5 times the text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I guess the units are physical pixels. The fact that the documentation doesn't state what the units are (it just says "Must be a floating point value"), and that you don't get to choose which units (pixels or dip), was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the unit is pd, not pixels.

Comment: Not so. It remains an unresolved [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21238)