# Buttonstyle - Dimension types not allowed

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I have styled a button, as follows, but got several error messages.

```
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0dp"
    android:shadowDy="0dp"
    android:shadowRadius="5dp"
```

> Dimension types not allowed (at 'shadowDy' with value '0dp').
>   Dimension types not allowed (at 'shadowRadius' with value '5dp').
>   Dimension types not allowed (at 'shadowDx' with value '0dp').

```
buttonshape.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#198CFF"
        android:startColor="#449DEF"
        android:endColor="#2F6699"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: Try it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854935/textviewshadowdx-dy-radius-in-dip/5776803#5776803

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use units, for example:

```
   android:shadowDx="2"
   android:shadowDy="2"
   android:shadowRadius="5"
   android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
```