# How to avoid a duplicate style item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

How do I avoid duplicate style items in the below example?

I have `textSize 30sp` with the style - `TextStyle`.

```
<style name="TextStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

The same `textSize 30sp` I am using in the below style. Is there any method apply the `textsize`- without duplicate writing of the style?

```
<style name="bottomText">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">150dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let one Style inherit from the other:

```
 <style name="bottomText" parent="TextStyle">
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">150dp</item>
  </style>
```

the style "bottomText" then has all attributes defined in "TextStyle", but can still be overwritten within bottomText.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="TextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomText" parent="@style/TextStyle">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">150dp</item>
</style>

<style name="boldText" parent="@style/bottomText">
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Another approach:

```
<style name="bottomText.BoldText">
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

In last two cases boldText inherits from bottomText which defines `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="TextStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
   </style>

<style name="bottomText" parent="@style/TextStyle">
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">150dp</item>
  </style>
```

let style of bootomText Inheritance  the TextStyle

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: text bold?? Is there bold attr on TextView in android? if you just want to set text attr, you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297437/shadow-effect-for-a-text-in-android/3297562#3297562

Comment: Of course, there is a `bold` value for TextView's `android:textStyle` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you don't need that second style since you need to set a `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the xml. You can just set that height and width when you create your `layout` and just use the `style="@styles/TextStyle"`. If there's a reason you can't do it this way, please explain the problem a little better