# How to give bold shadow over normal text in android textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, shadow

i need to give shadow over text view in android.
i have already tried using this code

```
android:shadowColor="#c3c3c3"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="15"
```

but not getting result the shadow is very thin.
i want exact as

[image].

in picture shadow is very strong shadow over text but by using above code with many values i am not getting that effect any suggestion for it.

Comment: Not really Holo like design...

Comment: check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373264/1396082

Comment: @LEO87 i have tried this already but not get success to find exact effect