# Android elevation shadow appearing in Android Studio preview but not on my KitKat device

Tags: android

I have the follow TextView tag in my Activity layout

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        android:text="TEST TEST TEST"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="120dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

The shadow from the elevation is appearing in Android Studio's render of the activity, but when I run the app on my KitKat phone (Galaxy S4), the shadow is nonexistent. Is this a common problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `elevation` property is only supported on Android 5.0+. `android:elevation` will be ignored on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since your device does not support elevation, you can add your own drop shadows to your textview. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373264/4739608 , this should help.