# How can make Text Shadow in android?

Tags: android

How can i make shadow Text in android please help me

Like this

[image]

Comment: I think this post will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297437/shadow-effect-for-a-text-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
    android:shadowDx="3"
    android:shadowDy="3"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="Hello Shadow Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and define color as

```
  <color name="text_shadow">#58ACFA</color>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to give shadow effect to text

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="@color/White"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView android:textColor="@color/Black"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="Simple Shadow"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:padding="2dp"
 android:shadowColor="@color/TransparentGrey" 
 android:shadowDx="3"
 android:shadowDy="3" 
 android:shadowRadius="0.01" />
</LinearLayout>
```

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="White">#FFF</color>
 <color name="Black">#000</color>
 <color name="Grey">#7F7F7F</color>
 <color name="DarkGrey">#4F4F4F</color>
 <color name="Green">#0F0</color>
 <color name="TransparentGrey">#7F000000</color>
</resources>
```

gradiant.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <gradient 
 android:startColor="@color/White" 
 android:endColor="@color/Black" 
 android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

output

[image]