# Android How does TextView Shadow work

Tags: android, textview, shadow

I have textview with shadow to show,I put parameters of Shadow ShadowX and ShadowY and ShadowRadius like in following XML code

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowColor="#e41919"
            android:shadowRadius="0.6"
            android:text="@string/nader"
            android:textColor="#e1e1e1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

but I don't know that how Shadow X ,Shadow Y and Shadow Radius  work in background
and how android evaluate these parameters values conceptually?

> android:shadowDx – specifies the X-axis offset of shadow. You can give -/+ values, where -Dx draws a shadow on the left of text and +Dx on the right
>
> android:shadowDy – it specifies the Y-axis offset of shadow. -Dy specifies a shadow above the text and +Dy specifies below the text.
>
> android:shadowRadius – specifies how much the shadow should be blurred at the edges. Provide a small value if shadow needs to be prominent.

how does android logically use these above attribute values without specifying values in any format like ,please send me any tutorial URL about these attributes

> dp
>   pixel

if you have any tutorial and reference about shadow parameter then please help and send me the Blogs URL tutorial about these properties of Shadow

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297437/shadow-effect-for-a-text-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Refer the following link:

http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-textview-text-shadow.html

You have to take the 3-4 textview's in yout xml file, then change the shadowDx, shadowDy and color of the shadow for each textview, then you will observe the difference.

Comment: thank you dear for your good suggestion,but the my question is that how did the ShadowX and ShafowY work internally and logically ,l need more Conceptual Understanding So I can customize Show of TextView  like following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping

Answer (score 0):

Add the attributes in the TextView XML:

```
android:shadowColor="#ff6ccDze0"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:shadowDy="6"
android:shadowDx="7"
```

Comment: Please alter your answer with an explanation of your code.

Comment: dear I don't need any examples of TextView shadow,I need that how does ShadowX ,ShadowY and ShadoRadius work logically and concptually on TextView Android,how did these attributes effect the shadow of textview

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with different values, I noticed that

- a negative value for dx moves (i.e. translates) the **whole** shadow to the left
- a positive value for dx moves (i.e. translates) the **whole** shadow to the right
- a negative value for dy moves (i.e. translates) the **whole** shadow upwards
- a positive value for dy moves (i.e. translates) the **whole** shadow downwards

The distance is determined by value: the greater the absolute value, the greater the distance.