# How to add shadow to title in Android toolbar?

Tags: android, layout, shadow

I just followed this tutorial, got everything good, but I need to add some kind of shadow to the text, so it can be readable.. Does anyone knows how to do this?

https://medium.com/alexander-schaefer/adding-a-background-image-to-an-android-toolbar-in-the-right-way-1f4baa008404

Thanks!

My currently output:
[image: print]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [Shadow Effect for a Text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297437/shadow-effect-for-a-text-in-android), or add inside layout some translucent image with gradient below text