# How to change a TextView's style at runtime

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an android app on which, when the user taps a `TextView`, I would like to apply a defined style.

I thought to find a `textview.setStyle()` but it doesn't exists. I tried

```
textview.setTextAppearance();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I've read somewhere that this is not possible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view . But you can set some properties  separately.

Comment: Did you try: textView.setTextTypeface? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)

Comment: @Falmarri Have YOU looked through the TextView api documents? If so, maybe you could say something more constructive.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I did this by creating a new XML file `res/values/style.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="boldText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="normalText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#C0C0C0</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I also have an entries in my "strings.xml" file like this:

```
<color name="highlightedTextViewColor">#000088</color>
<color name="normalTextViewColor">#000044</color>
```

Then, in my code I created a ClickListener to trap the tap event on that TextView:
**EDIT:**
**As from API 23 'setTextAppearance' is deprecated**

```
    myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view){
                    //highlight the TextView
                    //myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
       myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
    } else {
       myTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.boldText);
    }
     myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.highlightedTextViewColor);
                }
            });
```

To change it back, you would use this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.normalText);
} else{
   myTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.normalText);
}
myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.normalTextViewColor);
```

Comment: Actually this doesnt work with shadow styles. If you would like to change the shadow you must do it this way: 
lockText.setShadowLayer(20, 4, 4, 0xFFFF0000);

Comment: To avoid the SDK checking you can use TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(myTextView, R.style.myStyle);

Answer (score 91):

Like Jonathan suggested, using `textView.setTextTypeface` works, I just used it in an app a few seconds ago.

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); // Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.ITALIC etc.
```

Comment: You can use
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView..setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

Comment: textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD) is what worked for me. Of course, you could use 1 instead but I guess it's not a good practice to enter constants manually. Better use predefined variables in libraries.

Comment: Don't encourage people to use ints instead of constants

Comment: Good one! My mistake was that I was sending my old typeface in first parameter. So it does work when I change NORMAL -> BOLD but not BOLD -> NORMAL. I didn't know the first parameter could be null! Now it works fine for me!

Answer (score 12):

```
TextView tvCompany = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.tvCompany);
tvCompany.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

You an set it from code. [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html)

Answer (score 2):

i found `textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);` to be the simplest method.

Comment: This changes the Typeface. _not_ the style as specified by the OP.

Comment: True, still this was the simplest method - and as far as I recall the only method - at the time of the post. I'm not sure if a new API method was added in the meantime which enables changing the "style" to bold without altering the typeface. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try this line of code.

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

here , it will get current Typeface from this textview and replace it using new Typeface. New typeface here is `DEFAULT_BOLD` but you can apply many more.

Comment: The OP wants to change the style, _not_ the Typeface.

Answer (score 0):

See doco for setText() in TextView
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

> To style your strings, attach android.text.style.* objects to a SpannableString, or see the Available Resource Types documentation for an example of setting formatted text in the XML resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which style you want to set, you have to use different methods. TextAppearance stuff has its own setter, TypeFace has its own setter, background has its own setter, etc.