# Android set text style programmatically

Tags: android

I need to access the following -

```
android:textStyle(of a digital clock control)
```

programmatically, how do I do this?

Comment: refer this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime

Comment: You need get whats the text font currently set for widget like textview or edit text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`setTypeface(typeface, style)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

For a textview :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

To set the typeface `tv.setTypeface(tf);`

To get the current typeface set use `tv.getTypeface();`