# Change text size and color in one time?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I create many activities and classes in my app. However I have a function to change font size and color in every activity. This function changes text in own activity. When I go to other activity I must change textSize and color again. How can I create a function to change TextView in many classes and activities in one shot?

My app Structure:

```
Main.java   main.xml/
Suad1.java  suad1.xml/
Suad2.java  suad2.xml/
Suad3.java  suad3.xml/
Suad4.java  suad4.xml/
```

I want to change these activity in one time. Here my code in Suad1.class.

```
public void ShowDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
    seek.getProgress();
    seek.setMax(100);

    popDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.conp);
    popDialog.setTitle(R.string.menu_settings);
    popDialog.setView(seek);
    try {

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                subtitles.setTextSize(progress);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    popDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items , -1,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            int i;
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                i = item;
                if(items[i] =="Blue") {
                    subtitles.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font3));
                } else if(items[i] == "Yellow") {
                    subtitles.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font1));
                } else if(items[i]== "Red") {
                    subtitles.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font2));
                }
            }
        }
    );

    // Button
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(Suad1.this, "Your setting is complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    );
    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();
}
```

And two more questions:

1. Can I update SeekBar when out dialog and back again?
2. Can I have two Titles or more in one AlertDialog?

Comment: You should use `styles` or even a `theme` to change the appearance of widgets along the entire activity/application

Comment: Oh man. I'm just new Beginner. Do you have a simple way ?

Comment: The _simpler_ way is how you are already doing it, which turns considerably _complicated_ once you have multiple views and/or activities.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class with method which you can use in multiple Activities for Changing TextView text,color :

```
public class ChangetextAttr {


public Activity context;

public ChangetextAttr(Activity context){

        this.context=context;
}

// Create an Method for Changing TextView Attributes

public void settextViewAttr(Activity activity, TextView txtView){

   txtView.setTextSize(15);
   txtView.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.font1));
   //....
}
```

and from Any Activity you can settextViewAttr method for setting TextView Attributes :

```
   ChangetextAttr obj=new ChangetextAttr(Your_Activity.this);
   obj.settextViewAttr(this,any_textview_instance);
```

Comment: Again: Although defining your own class just to do what the `styling` or `theming` mechanisms already do would not be a very wise idea...

Answer (score 0):

Hey create a(Customized textview) class which extends TextView and do whatever you want to do for the textview like changing text color and textstyle. now use this class in all your xml's . if your class name MyTextView. then your xml should be like the following...

```
   <urpackage.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Although defining your own class just to do what the `styling` or `theming` mechanisms already do would not be a very wise idea...

Comment: if it is the case u can provide the wise solution for this

Comment: @Taruni: There you go, wiser solution provided... now don't tell me you don't like my solution most...

Answer (score 0):

*Android* provides you with mechanisms already to change the appearance of widgets, via *Styles* and *Themes*.

Here is how you define a style that sets the text size and color of any view that holds text:

```
<style name="BigColoredText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

and here is how you apply it to a `TextView`:

```
<TextView style="@style/BigColoredText" .../>
```

*Styles* can only be supplied to `View`s at construction time, you cannot change it afterwards. However, you can programmatically change the `textAppearance` with is the subset of a style that refers to `text` attributes via:

```
TextView v = ...;
v.setTextAppearance(R.styles.BigColoredText);
```

Now, if you want *all* `TextView`s within your *Activity* or *Application* using that same style (or at least use it by default), then you need a *Theme*:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/BigColoredText</item>
</style>
```

and then apply the *theme* to either the entire *Application* or one or more *Activities* in your manifest:

```
<application or activity android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" .../>
```

Or you can change it programmatically at runtime via:

```
Activity activity = ...;
activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyTheme);
```

Comment: This can change TextView ? I just want to modify this function (code above) to change TextView in all activity.

Comment: @T2terBKK: calling `setTheme` will change the appearance of all `TextView`s in the _current_ `Activity`. Its up to you to then remember the theme chosen and apply it at the beginning of every activity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1- What you need is two styles (Bold & normal) and change between the used style for Text using `View.setTextAppearance`. Check Android [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime).

2- To update seekbar with a value that is unchanged from View to View, then you need to keep its progress in a shared preference for e.g. and set the progress in onResume.

3- Consider using a custom Dialog instead (you can define it in XML as you wish). Or you can include `/n` to have multi lines in the Title string

Comment: Oh... I just want to change TextSize and color  every activity in one time. not bold these textView. Thank for advance.

Comment: It is the same, set two styles one for wach color and textsize.

Comment: You can use a theme as in K-ballo's answer, but you will have to call setTheme before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).