# How to clear formatting from an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an *EditText*, and can add formatting such as bold, italic....but how can I remove it? I've looked into getSpans, filters, and other non-string things and haven't been able to make sense of them! Ideally, I'd like to be able to clear specific tags and all tags set around the selected text.

***Update with my solution:***

```
private String getSelectedText(){
        int start = Math.max(mText.getSelectionStart(), 0);
        int end = Math.max(mText.getSelectionEnd(), 0);
        return mText.getText().toString().substring(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end));
    }
private void clearFormat(){
        int s1 = Math.max(mText.getSelectionStart(), 0);
        int s2 = Math.max(mText.getSelectionEnd(), 0);
        String text = getSelectedText(); if(text==""){ return; }
        EditText prose = mText;
        Spannable raw = new SpannableString(prose.getText());
        CharacterStyle[] spans = raw.getSpans(s1, s2, CharacterStyle.class);
        for (CharacterStyle span : spans) {
            raw.removeSpan(span);
        }
        prose.setText(raw);
        //Re-select
        mText.setSelection(Math.min(s1,s2), Math.max(s1, s2));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but how can I remove it?

Call `removeSpan()` on the `Spannable`.

For example, this method from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search) searches for a search string in the contents of a `TextView` and assigns it a background color, but only after removing any previous background colors:

```
private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right track! With just a few adjustments needed :)

Comment: how do i remove a particular tag using remove span ?

Comment: @Kutbi: I do not know what a "tag" is here. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can explain **in detail** what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

what you could try is:

1- Create a custom style where your EditText will have "such as bold, italic..."

2- Be aware of using `R.style.normalText` to change it back to it's normal style at runtime

3- Change this styles depending on the behaviour you want to achieve via `setTextAppearance(Context context, int resid)`

Here is an example i found googling [How to change a TextView's style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime)

Edit: as your question is "How to clear formatting from an EditText" here is the specific answer as code:

```
editTextToClearStyle.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.normalText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comment of the snippet below.

```
if (makeItalic) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(textViewDescription.getText());
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
    this.textViewDescription.setText(spanString);
} else {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(
        textViewDescription.getText().toString()); // NOTE: call 'toString()' here!
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
    this.textViewDescription.setText(spanString);
}
```

... just get the raw string characters by calling the `toString()` method.