# How to add shadow on custom text?

Tags: android, textview, dropshadow

i  tried with xml file and with code to add shadow to custom font without any success

my code is

```
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gillsans.ttf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text

Comment: thanks ashish but its in what is am trying to achieve is to use custom text with some shadow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this:

**Activity.class** :

```
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gillsans.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(tf);
////////////

    Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(2, 0, 4, 60,
                    new int[]{Color.parseColor("#b4e391"),Color.parseColor("#61c419"),Color.parseColor("#b4e391")},
                    new float[]{0, 3,1}, TileMode.MIRROR);
            text.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

**main.xml:**

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:shadowDx="5"
            android:shadowDy="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

            android:shadowColor="#67587686"

            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="99%" />
```

Comment: Akki , if you have any issue then tell me bez this code perfectly working for me??

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the related shadow attributes?

```
android:shadowColor
android:shadowDx
android:shadowDy
android:shadowRadius
```

Comment: yes 
without above mention code its working fine with once i change the font type shadow disappears.