# Glowing text contour in android.

Tags: android, text, contour, glow

how can I add a glowing text contour in android?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Actually I don't know. But it looks like it.. But it is a good example. However I would like to do it with a different font.

Comment: @Xazen : see this maybe helpful :[How to make text glow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692804/how-to-make-text-glow)

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I need to do it with contour.

Comment: @Xazen: then use `LinearGradient` for this see my ans : [add shadow on custom text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646775/how-to-add-shadow-on-custom-text/9647017#9647017)

Answer (score 8):

Add shadow to your textview with x , y = 0 and Radious value as much as you like to glow.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Glowing" 
android:textSize="40sp" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:shadowColor="#0000ff" 
android:textColor="#C02938" 
android:shadowDx="0.0" 
android:shadowDy="0.0" 
android:shadowRadius="10"/>
```

Comment: can this be done only when the text is touched? like a button?

Comment: you can use this in a button tag too, not only in textview