# how to add shadow on text in android?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - shadow on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text)

how to add shadow on text in android?

i am using this.

text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;

but this is not working in android devices...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested with the tag text-shadow?

```
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
```

Comment: this text shadow problem in android

Answer (score 1):

Android browser renders the style `background-image` very poorly. Here's the useful [article](http://mbudm.com/2011/03/android-css-background-image-blurriness/) on this topic.

Better to use the following: `android:shadowDx`, `android:shadowDy`, `android:shadowRadius`.

For instance:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="@color/light_font"
              android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
              android:shadowDx="1"
              android:shadowDy="1"
              android:shadowRadius="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is for background,
If you want to add shadow in text it's done using this CSS,

text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;

or

text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #Ff0000;

Comment: Note that there's a nasty android bug where text-shadow is ignored if the blur radius is set to less than one pixel. This caught me out for ages..  Here's the bug report http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7531

Comment: this text shadow problem in android