# Can't set TextView shadow programmatically

Tags: android, textview, shadow

I'm creating a TextView dynamically and set shadow to it using the method posted here: [Android - shadow on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text)

But it doesn't work. The style is applied (put textSize item to test, and it works), but the shadow doesn't appear.

TextView:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPars = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutPars.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL); 
tv.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
tv.setText(label);
tv.setTextSize(11);
tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.BlackShadow);
```

Style:

```
<style name="BlackShadow">  
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26dip</item>
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
tv.setShadowLayer(1.5f, -1, 1, Color.LTGRAY);
```

From documentation

```
setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int shadowColor)
```

This draws a shadow layer below the main layer, with the specified offset and color, and blur radius.

For more information please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29

Comment: why -1.5f? It does not look like a typo to me

Comment: @Alpaslan these values are for example only, change these as per your requirement.