# Double Color Text

Tags: java, android

i have app include textview , i wonder if i can show the text with double color ,

for changing the color of the  text easy to achieve by the following code :

```
android:textColor="#B22222"
```

but what i need to achieve is :

**text with two different color**

or

**text with color filled inside other color**

as exampled image below :

[image]

so i can apply that  to the  whole text or part of it inside the textview .

I searced the net for any example but i cant find one ,

any advice will be appreciated , thanks

**UPDATE:**

Iused shadow in text XML , it gave aclose shape of what im looking for , but not exact
double color as previous image ,

my shadow code :

```
  <TextView   
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="hi"  
 android:textStyle="bold"  
 android:textSize="150dp"  
 android:typeface="sans"  
 android:textColor="#0000ff"  
 android:shadowColor="#B22222"   
 android:shadowRadius="2.0"  
 android:shadowDy="10.0" 
 android:shadowDx="10.0"         /> 
<TextView    
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
 android:text="hi"     
 android:textStyle="bold"  
 android:textSize="150dp" 
 android:typeface="sans" 
 android:textColor="#0000ff"  
 android:shadowColor="#B22222"  
 android:shadowRadius="25.0"         />
```

**output result as below image :**

[image]

Any idea to get same shape of text in first image , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use [shadowColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ashadowColor), [shadowDx](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ashadowDx), [shadowDy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ashadowDy) and [shadowRadius](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ashadowRadius) to achieve a very similar effect to the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I can give some useful Examples. If you can refer this Example to make your own Color and apply shadows for your text. Examples are [Text Shadows](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/378#) and [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Please refer this link and make your own color and shadow. This answer is very helpful to you.

Comment: Refer this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text

Answer (score 0):

Its working find for me with two color white and red.

```
TextView textPaint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        textPaint.getPaint().setShadowLayer(2, 5, 5, Color.RED);
```