# How to draw shadow under text using drawText?

Tags: android, paint

I used:

```
paint.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

But, the result is not that beautiful.
Is this the only way to draw shadow?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text) but answer is for TextView.

Comment: You could draw your shadow and after your text over it. Just a little down and a little to the right.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487314/603233