# Android textview shadow doesn't work using style.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview that I set its style to a style I made with a shadow. I declared the settings I want in the style.xml `InfoTextstyle` and set the textview style to the style but it doesn't work.

This is the **style.xml**:

```
<style name="InfoTextStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item> <- works
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item> <- works
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#ff0000</item> <- don't works*
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">5.0</item> <- *
        <item name="android:shadowDx">2.0</item> <- *
        <item name="android:shadowDy">2.0</item> <- *                  
</style>
```

& this is the **activity_main.xml**:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/brightness"
     style="@style/InfoTextStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:text="@string/brightness"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I'm new to android, so I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: does the color of the text changes according to the style?, also I recommend you to use #RRGGBB not #RGB

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

1. Look on a real device, not in Eclipse "Graphical layout" which does not support text shadow.
2. Decrease the shadow radius to 1. The larger the radius, the more blurred the shadow is.
3. Check if the style file you wrote in in the main "values" directory or under values-?dpi. Maybe your device dpi does not target your style file

Comment: So nice, thanks for help! I thought the shadow is displayed directly in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XML code in your TextView declaration instead of using Styles

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="A light blue shadow."  
    android:shadowColor="#00ccff"  
    android:shadowRadius="1.5"  
    android:shadowDx="1"  
    android:shadowDy="1"  
    />
```

-android:shadowColor Shadow color in the same format as textColor.

-android:shadowRadius Radius of the shadow specified as a floating point number.

-android:shadowDx The shadow’s horizontal offset specified as a floating point number.

-android:shadowDy The shadow’s vertical offset specified as a floating point number.

Also use this link to pick your Color code 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

**EDIT:**

```
TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textv.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

Also take a look at this link for Style way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487340/1364896

Comment: I have used your code but still does not work. anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: It should work, try to increase the values to notice it...Also try the programmatically way in the Edit for faster shaddow @MaximilianMüller

Comment: For API Level 21 and above you can use elevation attribute in xml of textview for shadow effect.