# Android text shadow not working

Tags: android, textview

In my android app, I dynamically make a text view and assign it this style:

```
<style name="keys">
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item> 
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
</style>
```

All the properties works except the shadow...
I'm also not talking about the eclipse preview. I mean it doesn't work when I run it on the phone (physical).

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: anyone can check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761610/4307338

Answer (score 2):

Separate out the text attributes from the layout attributes, and apply them with the `textAppearance` attribute. That is, instead of:

```
<style name="keys">
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
</style>
```

You would have:

```
<style name="Keys">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item> 
</style>

<style name="KeysAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
</style>
```

and in your layout, instead of:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/keys"/>
```

You would have:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/Keys"
    android:textAppearance="@style/KeysAppearance" />
```

Comment: You can't set a style at runtime. You'll have to apply these attributes manually on the `TextView` (e.g. `myTextView.setShadowColor()`). Alternately, make a layout containing just the `TextView` with the styles set, and inflate it at runtime.