# Create a bitmap of text with shadow

Tags: android, text, bitmap, draw, shadow

I want to create a bitmap of text with shadow, but I can't get good result. The problem is, when I directly draw the text, it looks good, but when I draw the text to a bitmap, and then draw the bitmap, it looks ugly.

Code:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("HELVETICA", Typeface.NORMAL));
        paint.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
        Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas2.drawText("Dec Use", 100, 100, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final boolean useBitmap = true;
        if(useBitmap){
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
        else{
            canvas.drawText("Dec Use", 100, 100, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

When `useBitmap` is set to `false`, the result looks like this

[image]

When `useBitmap` is set to `true`, the result looks like this

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 6):

The loss of quality seems to be related to the bitmap.
You can get a better result by using a **grey shadow** and using **bigger bitmaps** (even if it means resing it after).

```
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas2.drawText("Dec Use", 200, 200, paint);

    paint.setShadowLayer(20, 0, 0, Color.GRAY);
    canvas2.drawText("Dec Use", 200, 200, paint);
```

[image]

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text/2487314#2487314)

Comment: Grey color makes the shadow dimmer, so it looks better. but I don't think it actually solves this problem.

Comment: The problem is the quality of the bitmap, which can be solved with bigger bitmaps (or a Bitmap.Config trick but I don't think so).